# How can I see that my java service in an ec2 instance is up or down visually through graph or chart at run time in new relic

Tags: amazon-web-services, newrelic

I have added a java service to my ec2 instance, which is running. I want to see that my service is up or down on the instance. Also I want to see it visually like through a chart or graph, I know we can check through logs, I want to see it visually which I can display on the dashbaord on a TV screen.

I tried using new relic Java agent and micrometer new relic registry, It enrolls my service to be on the new relic but does not show any direct pictorial representation for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you enable health check , in Prometheus format and consume that?
In health check look for if service is logically down or not. even if port number is up may be it is not able to server request. Cheers!!!

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I am using java service with springboot framework.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are using SpringBoot.
You can use its [actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html) especially the `health` endpoint.
You can then monitor this endpoint with your favourite monitoring solution and create an appropriate graph.